# test rails controllers that are not in spec/controllers with rspec 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, rspec2

rspec expects your controller specs to be in /spec/controllers.  I have some modules that are included in my controllers.  The only way to test them, near as I can tell, is to create a dummy controller, include the module in it, and test from there.  The problem is that the module specs are in /spec/lib/module, and so ControllerExampleGroup is not included, which means I can't call the helper methods get "action" etc.

I can manually import these, which gets me most of the way there, but I then get this error:

```
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching
 line from backtrace undefined method
 `path_set' for nil:NilClass
  activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in
 `method_missing'
  rspec-rails-2.2.1/lib/rspec/rails/view_rendering.rb:68
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:291:in
 `instance_eval'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:291:in
 `instance_eval_with_rescue'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:39:in
 `run_in'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:70:in
 `run_all'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:70:in
 `each'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:70:in
 `run_all'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:106:in
 `run_hook'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:194:in
 `eval_after_eachs'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:194:in
 `each'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:194:in
 `eval_after_eachs'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:130:in `run_after_each'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:44:in `run'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:88:in `with_around_hooks'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:37:in `run'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:81:in `with_pending_capture'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:80:in `catch'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:80:in `with_pending_capture'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:36:in `run'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:261:in
 `run_examples'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:257:in
 `map'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:257:in
 `run_examples'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:231:in
 `run'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:232:in
 `run'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:232:in
 `map'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:232:in
 `run'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:27:in
 `run'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:27:in
 `map'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:27:in
 `run'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:12:in `report'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:24:in
 `run'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:in
 `run_in_process'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in
 `run'
  rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in
 `autorun'
  /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/rspec:19
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Looks like manually importing doesn't quite work either, I'm getting:

Answer (score 9):

If you have a spec that's not in one of the standard locations, you can always tell rspec by passing a :type attribute to the describe method:

```
describe MyController, :type => :controller do
    ...
end
```

For specing modules that are meant to be included by a controller, rspec 2 has a very handy way to create anonymous controllers.

```
describe MyModule do

    context "when included by a controller", :type => :controller do
        controller do      # anonymous subclass of ActionController::Base
            include MyModule

            def index
                head :ok
            end
        end

        it "works" do
          get "index"
          response.should be_success
        end
    end
end
```

More info here in the rspec docs (generated from Cucumber features): http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/dir/controller-specs/anonymous-controller

Comment: Great example on how to test controller behavior specified in library modules!